# How can I use the ruamel.yaml rtsc mode?

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

I've been working on creating a YAML re-formatter based on ruamel.yaml (which you can see [here](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/blob/be4704e6ee9518d37af90216440a4a066df7db90/src/ansiblelint/yaml_utils.py#L228-L745)).
I'm currently using version 0.17.20.

Cleaning up comments and whitespace has been difficult. I want to:

- ensure there is only one space before the `#` for EOL comments
- align full line comments with the key or item immediately following
- remove duplicate blank lines so there is at most one blank line

To get closer to achieving that, I have a custom Emitter class where I extend `write_comment` to adjust the comments just before writing with `super().write_comment(...)`. However, the Emitter does not know about which key or item comes next because comments are generally attached as post comments.

As I've studied the `ruamel.yaml` code to figure out how to do this, I found the `rtsc` mode (Round Trip Split Comments) which looks fantastic because it separates `EOLComment`, `BlankLineComment` and `FullLineComment` instead of lumping them together.

From what I can tell, the `Parser` and `Scanner` have been adjusted to capture the comments. So, loading is (mostly?) implemented with this "NEWCMNT" implementation. But Emitter.write_comment expects `CommentToken` instead of comment line numbers, so dumping does not work yet.

If I update my Emitter.write_comment method, is that enough to finish dumping? Or what else might be necessary? In one of my tries, I ran into a `sys.exit` in `ScannedComments.assign_eol()` - what else is needed to finish that?

PS: I wouldn't normally ask how to collaborate on StackOverflow, but this is not a bug report or a feature request, and I'm trying/failing to use a new (undocumented) feature, so I'm filing this here instead of sourceforge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtsc` is work in progress cq work started but unfinished. It's internals will almost certainly change.

Two of the three points you indicate can relatively easy be implemented:

- set the column of each comment to 0 ( by recursively going over a loaded data structure similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71333052/1307905) ) if the column is before the position of the end of the value on a line, you'll get one space between the value and the column
- at the same time doing the recursion in the previous point. Take each comment value and do something like:

  ```
     value = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in value.splitlines()
     while '\n\n\n' in value:
          value = value.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
  ```

The indentation to the following element is difficult, depends on the
data structure etc. Given that these are full line comments, I suggest
you do some postprocessing of the YAML document you generate:

1. find a full line comment, gather full line comments until next line is
   not full line comment (i.e. some "real" YAML). Since full line comments
   are in column[0] if the previous stuff is applied, you don't have to
   track if you are in a (multi-line) literal or folded scalar string where
   one of the lines happens to start with `#`
2. determine number of spaces
   before real YAML and apply these to the full line comments.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
   # the following is a example YAML doc
a:
- b: 42


       # collapse multiple empty lines 
  c: |
    # this is not a comment
    it is the first line of a block style literal scalar
    processing this gobbles a newline which doesn't go into a comment
 # that is unless you have a (dedented) comment directly following


  d: 42       # and some non-full line comment
 

  e:   # another one
 # and some more comments to align
     f: glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser gate
"""
 

def redo_comments(d):
    def do_one(comment):
        if not comment:
            return
        comment.column = 0
        value = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in comment.value.splitlines()) + '\n'
        while '\n\n\n' in value:
            value = value.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
        comment.value = value

    def do_values(v):
        for x in v:
            for comment in x:
                do_one(comment)

    def do_loc(v):
        if v is None:
            return
        do_one(v[0])
        if not v[1]:
            return
        for comment in v[1]:
            do_one(comment)

    if isinstance(d, dict):
        do_loc(d.ca.comment)
        do_values(d.ca.items.values())
        for val in d.values():
            redo_comments(val)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        do_values(d.ca.items.values())
        for elem in d:
            redo_comments(elem)

def realign_full_line_comments(s):
    res = []
    buf = []
    for line in s.splitlines(True):
        if not buf:
            if line and line[0] == '#':
                buf.append(line)
            else:
                res.append(line)
        else:
            if line[0] in '#\n':
                buf.append(line)
            else:
                # YAML line, determine indent
                count = 0
                while line[count] == ' ':
                    count += 1
                    if count > len(line):
                        break  # superfluous?
                indent = ' ' * count
                for cline in buf:
                    if cline[0] == '\n':  # empty
                        res.append(cline)
                    else:
                        res.append(indent + cline)
                buf = []
                res.append(line)
    return ''.join(res)


 
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
redo_comments(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=realign_full_line_comments)
```

which gives:

```yaml
# the following is a example YAML doc
a:
- b: 42

  # collapse multiple empty lines
  c: |
    # this is not a comment
    it is the first line of a block style literal scalar
    processing this gobbles a newline which doesn't go into a comment
  # that is unless you have a (dedented) comment directly following

  d: 42 # and some non-full line comment

  e: # another one
    # and some more comments to align
    f: glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser gate
```

Comment: Would you like any help with the `rtsc` stuff?

Comment: I'll try to put a working example later tonight (have to cook dinner now). Help is appreciated, so thanks for the offer. but rtsc is really in the experimentation phase, and other things (such as only one attribute for all of the special attachments instead of `.ca` ane `.fa`) need to happen. I just have to find some time and get back up to speed

Comment: Maybe drop all of the legacy API-compat bits so that there's less code to wade through. Just keep the latest API + the WIP newcmnt stuff. wdyt?

Comment: Here's [my approach](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/pull/1952/files#diff-cf16cc7c90d34cd800ca875c68cd59bcef54cf17818f81e8bc80943f09ef4c9dR705-R732) to fixing new line comments.
However, this will mangle multi-line strings with `#` like:
```- |\n
  # this is part of a string not a yaml comment\n
  # also not a yaml comment\n
\n
- something else\n
```

Any ideas on how I can avoid mangling strings with such a post-processor?

Comment: The legacy API is already dropped for the next minor release. I updated my answer which might need some tweaking. For multiline comments you actually need to `strip()` and not lstrip() to get every comment in the first column. Since the following lines are full line comments, they get indented in the post dump tranformation.

Comment: Some of the old stuff has to stay in place until there is a better ruamel.yaml.clib that I can use, it still is like the old libyaml and the PyYAML like API

Comment: And don't forget to pin your ruamel.yaml version to `ruamel.yaml<0.18`

Comment: WooHoo! That was very helpful. I found a few cases where I needed to preserve comment indentation, but your suggestion (move FLC so they can be distinguished unambiguously) led me to think about an alternative disambiguation by temporarily modifying the strings in the Emitter and then undoing that in the post-processor. Thank you for your quick help!
If you're interested, here's my new string protection: https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/pull/1956

Comment: Is there a branch where I can see your current `.ca` + `.fa` refactoring? How can I help?